# Deploy NestJs on AWS Amplify?

Tags: nestjs, aws-amplify

I have a ReactJS frontend and an NestJS backend. I deployed the frontend on AWS Amplify without any problems. Are there any ways to deploy the NestJS backend to AWS Amplify? If so, what configuration of the amplify.yml file is needed?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm looking for the same thing.